# "Task X in stage X failed X times" - Apache Spark EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have an error happening in spark running on Amazon EMR.
It doesn't always happen (most of the time the step finishes successfully) and when I work with more data and more nodes it happens more often.

I get a file already exists exception, but the question is what does it mean "failed 20 times"? What exactly failed? And why after 20 times it makes the whole application fail? Where is the configuration for that?
This is from the stderr of the step: (I blanked private info with *)

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 14139 in stage 151.0 failed 20 times, most recent failure: Lost task 14139.19 in stage 151.0 (TID 186***, ip-*-*-*-*.ec2.internal, executor 107): org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: File already exists:s3://**path**
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.upload.plan.RegularUploadPlanner.checkExistenceIfNotOverwriting(RegularUploadPlanner.java:36)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.upload.plan.RegularUploadPlanner.plan(RegularUploadPlanner.java:30)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.upload.plan.UploadPlannerChain.plan(UploadPlannerChain.java:37)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.create(S3NativeFileSystem.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:994)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.create(EmrFileSystem.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CsvOutputWriter.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

By the way, the file does not exist in this path before running the step.

Comment: It seems like you have it configured to retry each task up to 20 times, which is not the default. (I think the default is 3 or 4.) You probably want to look at the logs from the very first attempt that failed. It sounds like it may have successfully written the file but then failed for some other reason, causing it to retry, but then the task's output file was already present.

Comment: Where do I configure how many times to retry?